# Step by step drawing of Lewis diagram - how can I hide the bonds?

Tags: chemfig

For a chemistry assignment I need to produce a few Lewis diagrams. It was very simple with a linear molecule where I replaced the bond lines with `\quad`, but then I had to draw a 3D molecule and when I tried to hide the bonds by setting their color to white, they developed through the electron dots to my dismay.

How can I show the first step in Lewis diagram w/o bond lines and preserve the dots?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\setbondstyle{white}
\schemestart
\chemfig{O=[:30]\lewis{2:5:7:,S}(=[::60]O)=[::-60]O}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\setbondstyle{draw=none}` instead of `\setbondstyle{white}`:

[image]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\setbondstyle{draw=none}

\chemfig{O=[:45]\lewis{2:5:7:,S}(=[:90]O)=[:-45]O}

\end{document}
```